# Android Studio run

Tags: android-studio, plugins, revert

All started when I saw this two messages saying something about missing platforms and pluggins. I selected all the plugins and I clicked on install plugin from disk.

Now the buttons have become disabled, they are no longer green and 
my project file has many more folders than usual.

I was wondering if there is a way to restore or revert back Android the way it was before this mess with the plugins, or if reinstalling Android Studio will be the only choice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it does not always work, but have you tried a **restore point**? Also you can simply uninstall the unnecessary plugins from your Android studio. Just make sure you do not delete any important plugins.

If that doesn't work then you have to reinstall Android studio.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @kscs Np. Please accept the answer if it is helpful. :)